# pyspark get different varchar printSchema()

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

From spark dataframe when I run `df.printSchema()` all varchar(1), varchar(10), etc... becomes `string` Is there a way to differentiate varchars?

Doesn't have to be in pyspark. method to do it in spark sql is welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VarcharType(length)` can only be used in table schema, not functions/operators. This means you can use it in create table sql, but not dataFrame schema.